# Рег выражение для 

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Есть текст в котором есть картинки:

```
<img src="/images/uploads/2011-11-24/19442.jpg" alt="" width="200" height="112" />
```

Нужно два регулярных выражения:

- 1) Замена всех этих картинок моим
     текстом. Для каждого свой
- 2) У    каждого тэга img узнать href
     width    height alt

Заранее очень благодарен
Язык PHP

Answer (score 1):

```
$img = '<img src="/images/uploads/2011-11-24/19442.jpg" alt="" width="200" height="112" />';
function rpc($ar){return 'img'.$ar[1];}

//замена текстом. текст меняется в функции rpc()
echo preg_replace_callback('/<img src="\/images\/uploads\/[0-9\-]+\/([0-9]+).jpg[^>]+ \/>/', 'rpc', $img);

//ищем изображения
preg_match_all('/<img src="\/images\/uploads\/[0-9\-]+\/([0-9]+).jpg[^>]+ \/>/', $img, $m);
//перебираем нужные аттрибуты
foreach($m[0] as $v){
    preg_match_all('/((href|width|height|src)="[^"]*")/', $img, $t);
    // работа ведется с $t[1]
    print_r($t[1]);
}
```

Одно плохо: при перестановке аттрибутов местами с src или замене двойных кавычек одинарными механизм перестает работать. Поэтому модифицируйте его по мере надобности.

Comment: Спасибо большое!
А как бы так модифицировать:
берем из текста куски, которые начинаются с "<img" и заканчиваются "/>"
Берем этот кусок, передаем функции, которая уже разбирает все параметры и возвращает на что заменить

Comment: Используйте выражение /<img([^>]*)>/ - последним символом будет слеш, его можно обрезать.